# ui-selct onchange loading options from the server (upgraded from select2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I've recently upgraded from select2 to ui-select. I will show below how it was working using select2.

Context : I have a data of clients that needs to be filtered using ui-select.

Since the data of clients is large and could be more than 100000, I can't load it once then filter with ui-select. I need to make a query to the server onchange event (input change event with delay) and limit the results to 10.

Select2 Html :

```
<div
     st-input-event="change"
     st-search="_company_owner"
     style="width: 100%"
     ui-select2="ClientSelect2Options(true)"
     ng-model="company"
     name="company"
     class="text"
     class="form-control "
     placeholder="{{'SEARCH_BY_COMPANY' | translate}}"></div>
</td>
```

Select2 javascript :

```
$scope.ClientSelect2Options = function (allowClear) {
    return {
        allowClear: allowClear,
        id: function (e) { return e },
        ajax: {
            transport: function (params) {
                params.beforeSend = function (request) { request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token); };
                return $.ajax(params);
            },
            url: $rootScope.config.API_URI + '/company/query?limit=' + 10 + '&page=' + 1,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            quietMillis: 500,
            data: function (term) {
                return { query: { name: { "$regex": term, "$options": "i" } } }; },
            results: function (data) {
                return { results: data.result }; }
        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var id = $(element).select2('val');
            if (id && id.length > 0) {
                return companySrv.getCompanyById(id, function (res) {
                    if (res && res.success) {
                        callback(res.result);
                    } else { callback(null); }
                }, function () { callback(null); })
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Is it possible to query from the server using ui-select and how ?

Comment: I'll just remark that you shouldn't be using jQuery to make HTTP requests when angularjs has this functionality built in and even more importantly you shouldn't be using callback functions instead of promises.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i don't think es5 has promises. this is an old project. I mostly use typescript

Comment: jQuery AJAX is not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Instead use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to have the controller react to model changes.

Comment: @mike jQuery and angularjs provide promises for AJAX. You could also use a dedicated polyfill